# How to get RAW Google Ads Hit Data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-ads-api, google-ads-data-hub

So I'm trying to get raw google ads user data (including events, journeys etc), which i need to send to a Data-Warehouse.

Data From all my sources are send to Google Analytics & then to Data-Warehouse.

What i need is the RAW-Hit/Session level data that Google-Ads Monitor via Campaigns (from my account) to my Data-Warehouse directly, without any intermediate services.

Services like stitch-data does it directly, what all options do we have.

Thank you.

Comment: Google analytics doesnt work that way.  Check the Google analytics api or maybe a big query extract.

Comment: As @DaImTo said, check the [BigQuery Export for Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618?hl=en)